# How can I check the currentTitle of a UIButton in a switch?

Tags: swift, uibutton, switch-statement

I have a UIButton which changes the title in different situations. 
If you press the button the currentTitle should be checked by a Swift Switch (and certain Code executed).

The following isn't working:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.currentTitle {
    case "":
        //Code
    case "OK":
        //Code
    default:
}
}
```

Xcode just shows "Expected Pattern" (1st cause) and "Expected Expression" (2nd case)

Comment: Actually this code won't cause an `Expected Expression` error.

Comment: The important thing is to make sure that you have some sort of executable statement under each `case` and the `default`. `break` or `return` work too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem accidentally by adding questions marks

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
switch sender.currentTitle {
case ""?:
    //Code
case "OK"?:
    //Code
default:
    break
}
}
```

I don't know why but it works nevertheless thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

per the documentation, `UIButton.currentTitle` is of type `String?`. (optional type String)

Your `switch` statement is comparing an optional type to a non-optional type which is the reason you see errors.

Suggest first unwrapping the value before checking it's value with a `switch` like:

```
guard let title = sender.currentTitle() else { return }

switch title {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every case in a switch statement must have a line of code. If you don't want to do anything you can use `break`:

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.currentTitle {
    case "":
        //Code
    case "OK":
        //Code
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. There's a break but I forgot it here.

Comment: @C0d0r if you rebuild the project do the errors go away? Sometimes those kind of errors linger around when Xcode gets confused.

Comment: A rebuild isn't fixing anything